# how to change section background?

Tags: html, css

I am working with argon template and I am unable to change the section background

```css
.section-shaped .shape-style-1.shape-primary {
    background: linear-gradient(150deg, #281483 15%, #8f6ed5 70%, #d782d9 94%);
}
```

and I changed the background to the following value:

```css
background-image: url(../img/theme/landing3.jpg);
```

but it still shows the old background

Here is the HTML code:

```
    <div class="position-relative">
  <!-- Hero for FREE version -->
  <section class="section section-lg section-hero section-shaped">
    <!-- Background circles -->

    <div class="shape shape-style-1 shape-primary">

      <span class="span-150"></span>
      <span class="span-50"></span>
      <span class="span-50"></span>
      <span class="span-75"></span>
      <span class="span-100"></span>
      <span class="span-75"></span>
      <span class="span-50"></span>
      <span class="span-100"></span>
      <span class="span-50"></span>
      <span class="span-100"></span>

    </div>
```

Comment: Also, looks like you've set a property somewhere else too and want to overwrite it. At the end of the statement, add `!important` like `linear-gradient(150deg, #281483 15%, #8f6ed5 70%, #d782d9 94%) !important;` in case it doesn't works

Comment: Can you add the related HTML to your question?

Comment: did you clear cache?

Comment: does .shape-primary OR .shape-style-1 won't be enough?

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the quotation marks around your URL...

So instead of this:

```
background: url(../img/theme/landing3.jpg);
```

you need to do this:

```
background: url("../img/theme/landing3.jpg");
```